# How to change the color of certain parts of grid line in MpAndroidChart

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I am trying to use MPAndroidChart to make a Line chart in my app. I want to change the grid color of certain parts of the grid, when a value is selected on my graph.

Something like this:
[image: example image].

I know you can change the color of a grid line using :

```
xAxis.setGridColor()
//or
yAxis.setGridColor()
```

But this changes the color of the entire grid line either for the x-axis or y-axis. I need a way to set the color of only a section of the x-axis grid line, or y-axis grid line.

Comment: It is not clear to me what part of the chart you are trying to color. Is it a gradient, highlighter line or rectangle around values?

Comment: I am trying to color the rectangle around the value, or labels. When a value within that range is selected, in this particular case

Answer (score 0):

Please try this if you want to change axisline color, you can use below method.

```
mChart.getYAxis().setAxisLineColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.some_color));

mChart.getAxis().setAxisLineColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.some_color));
```

I don't think you can change color a section

Hope this will help!